# Split according to ":" in multiple lines

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a set of files composed as follows:

```
Product: Name
Description: description of product
```

I want to extract only the name and the description's content without the `'Product:'` and `'Description:'`. For this I do:

```
div = re.split('Product:\s+|Description:\s+', contentOfFile)
```

The problem is that I get a table of 3 elements instead of 2 with a ' ' (space) at the beginning. I don't know if space is always taken into account because I just want to get in this case:

```
["Name","description of product"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's simplify your example. What if we split on pipe instead of your regular expressions?

```
>>> "|a|b".split('|')
['', 'a', 'b']
```

If the string starts with a separator, split will add an extra empty element in the returned value. Now in your case the separator is a regular expression, but similarly, your string begins with something that matches that expression, so the first returned element is an empty string.

To address it, you can just skip the first element

```
div = re.split('Product:\s+|Description:\s+', contentOfFile)[1:]
```

Comment: good explanation, but I don't like this solution. It's very dependent on the text before the `:`, also I find this a little bit unclean because of the `[1:]`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `split`, use [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> re.findall(r":\s+(.*)", a)
['Name', 'description of product']
```

Using this solution, you won't be dependent on the text before the `:`, so even when you have:

```
SomeText: Name
BlaBlaBla: description of product
```

it'll extract `Name` and `description of product`. It's a good practice to write general solution for your problem and try to think about possible future scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution through split method without using regex.

```
>>> x = """Product: Name
Description: description of product"""
>>> [i.split(':')[1].lstrip() for i in x.split('\n')]
['Name', 'description of product']
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you can try the strip function instead of split...
it aldo help to remove space..
here a small example of split function

```
str1 = "Product: Name";
str2 = "Description: description of product";
print str1.lstrip('Product:, ');
print str2.lstrip('Description:, ');
```

and the output shown as below....

```
Name
description of product
```

Comment: OP has only one string that has multiple lines.

Comment: I think you don't understand how strip works: `"Description: Description of product".lstrip('Description:, ')` -> `'f product'`

Comment: This is the sample program of strip...but when you use in actual program it replace """"""description of program""""""" with its original description and i don't think the actual description start with """""description""""".....so the actual program work like this.....`str1 = "Product: Nvidia gtx650";  str2 = "Description: This is the graphics card develop by the NVIDIA company..";`  then you can apply this method.....